# Measuring size of functions with sonarqube

Tags: function, sonarqube, software-quality

I am new in the sonarqube world and was wondering if their is a way to meassure the size of functions ? In order to ensure that functions have less than 20 lines of source Code.

Comment: In what language?

Comment: With Python >= 2.7

Comment: That rule doesn't currently exist for Python at the method/function level.

Comment: Is it possible to write a own plugin for SonarPython ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule does not currently exist for Python, but it would be possible to write a custom plugin to add it.